# Is it possible to issue log messages from Neko to Apache logs?

Tags: neko

When using the nekotools server for development, I get all messages in the console. Is it be possible to activate those messages in Apache logs on a server, for debugging purposes?

Answer (score 0):

Answering own question since no answers yet.

In Haxe API I found `neko.Web.logMessage(msg:String):Void`, it allows sending custom messages to the webserver file logs. Not exactly what I was looking for though.